# Identifier name too long on composite primary key

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, composite-primary-key

I'm trying to define the following composite primary key :

```
$table->primary(array('user_id', 'object_id', 'object_type', 'object_filter_id'));
```

But I'm getting a "identifier name too long". Eloquent is trying to set this as the identifier : "users_watchlists_user_id_object_id_object_type_object_filter_id_primary"

Are there any workaround ?!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Found it. looking at the Blueprint.php source I can see that there's a 2nd argument $name to the primary() function...

```
public function primary($columns, $name = null)
```

Answer (score 2):

And it works for foreign keys too.

foreign(string|array $columns, string $name = null)